# Angularjs - instant search not working

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? searchCandidate() : null" ng-model="keyword" id="nav-third-input" placeholder="Rechercher" style="font-style:italic;color: #183046;letter-spacing: 1px;width: 90%;    background-color: transparent;">

<div class="list-prio-content-ul">
<p ng-if="data.length==0 && searching"> No result</p>
<!--RESULTS  -->
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index | searchFor:keyword">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 list-prio-content-bgc">
        <a href="/userprofile/[[item.id]]">
            <div class="list-prio-content-div">

                <div class="list-img">
                    <div ng-if="item.avatarPath">
                        <img src="/uploads/avatars/[[item.getAvatarPath()]]">
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="!item.avatarPath" style="width: 100%;">
                        <span class="initials">[[item.firstname.charAt(0) | uppercase ]][[item.lastname.charAt(0) | uppercase]]</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list-prio-content-txt">
                    <div class="list-prio-content-name-ul">
                        <p>
                            <span> [[item.firstname]]</span>
                            <strong>[[item.lastname | uppercase]]</span></strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){
    return function(arr, keyword){
        if(!keyword){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
            if(item.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) !== -1){
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
});

app.controller('recherche', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.searching = false;

    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
    }

    $scope.searchCandidate = () => {
        if ($scope.keyword === '') {
            $scope.data = [];
            $scope.searching = false;
            return;
        }
        else {
            $scope.searching = true;
            $http.get("search/" + $scope.keyword)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data;
                })
        }
    }
});
```

This is the first time I use angularjs. My search works when I press the "ENTER" key, but what I would like is that the search is instantaneous as on the following link:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/shahansha/pen/pvWJyv)

Can someone help me solve this problem please?

I thank you in advance

Comment: Then don't use ng-keyup and check if the enter key is the one that triggered the event. Use ng-change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-change` instead of `ng-keyup` change your code to

```
<input type="text" ng-change="searchCandidate()" ng-model="keyword" id="nav-third-input" placeholder="Rechercher" style="font-style:italic;color: #183046;letter-spacing: 1px;width: 90%;    background-color: transparent;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correct, You want the filtering to happen in real time, i.e as and when the user enters the keywords.
You can do it by calling your function on `ng-change`, like:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="filterFunction(keyword)" ng-model="keyword" id="nav-third-input" placeholder="Rechercher" style="font-style:italic;color: #183046;letter-spacing: 1px;width: 90%;    background-color: transparent;">
```

In your controller, Fetch the current keyword and make the filtering call, like:

```
 $scope.filterFunction = function(keyword) {
          // http call here and set the filtered values
          $http.get("search/" + keyword)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data;
          });
    }
```

Try this and let us know if this works for you.